# NodeJS 12 alarm in Github Workflow and Unexpected input(s) 'username', 'password', valid inputs are [dublicate]

Tags: python, dockerfile, continuous-integration, github-actions

Maybe there is a similar question or solution in stackoverflow or google, but I tried several methods, provided in the Interne, but it didn't help for me. Because I started to learn CI/CD only today, I am asking for a help with my CI/CD issue.

python-publish.yml (pipeline):

```
name: Python Package

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

env:
  CI: true

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: [ 3.8 ]
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash -l {0}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'
      - name: Initialize Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{matrix.python-version}}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Check if Docker is installed
        run: docker run hello-world
      - name: Push to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME}}
          password: ${{secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD}}
          tags: latest
```

Dockerfile (maybe you will need it):

```
FROM python:3.8

# Set environment variables
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_ENV=production
#ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=<YOUR_DATABASE_NAME>
#ENV MYSQL_USER=<YOUR_USERNAME>
#ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=<YOUR_PASSWORD>
#ENV MYSQL_HOST=<YOUR_HOST>
#ENV MYSQL_PORT=<YOUR_PORT>

# Create and set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy requirements file and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Run the application
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=80"]
```

Everything is working great, but I get two warnings and want to fix them:

1. Node.js 12 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 16: actions/setup-node@v2, actions/setup-python@v2. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/.
2. Unexpected input(s) 'username', 'password', valid inputs are ['add-hosts', 'allow', 'attests', 'build-args', 'build-contexts', 'builder', 'cache-from', 'cache-to', 'cgroup-parent', 'context', 'file', 'labels', 'load', 'network', 'no-cache', 'no-cache-filters', 'outputs', 'platforms', 'provenance', 'pull', 'push', 'sbom', 'secrets', 'secret-files', 'shm-size', 'ssh', 'tags', 'target', 'ulimit', 'github-token']

Answer (score 0):

- The latest version of the setup-node action is v3.6.0; you can get that with `actions/setup-node@v3.0.6`, or if you're okay with minor versions being updated transparently, `@v3`. This'll get rid of the node12 warning.
- The `build-push-action` action simply doesn't have any inputs for `username` or `password`; see the [definition in the `action.yml` file](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/v3.3.1/action.yml) as the source of truth.

  Notice that v3 is outdated here as well; the most recent version is v4.0.0. I highly recommend setting up dependabot to get [automated version updates](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/about-dependabot-version-updates).

Comment: I added login action before build-push-action but warnings didn't go away:
Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'username', 'password', 'repository', 'tag', valid inputs are ['add-hosts', 'allow', 'attests', 'build-args', 'build-contexts', 'builder', 'cache-from', 'cache-to', 'cgroup-parent', 'context', 'file', 'labels', 'load', 'network', 'no-cache', 'no-cache-filters', 'outputs', 'platforms', 'provenance', 'pull', 'push', 'sbom', 'secrets', 'secret-files', 'shm-size', 'ssh', 'tags', 'target', 'ulimit', 'github-token']

Comment: @worrum Are you still using `username` and `password` on `build-push-action`?

Comment: no, I don't. I am using docker@login-actionb

Comment: @worrum Can you link to the workflow run?